# Speed up a Mealy machine output algorithm - MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Let X be a mealy machine. More specifically, I'm representing it as a 3 by 3 by 2 by N array where N is the number of states. View it as a row of N 3 by 3 matrices and another such layer behind it. The layer behind gives the state transitions and the one in front the output values. So say I start from state N and input (x,y), I get output X(x,y,1,N) and then move to state X(x,y,2,N). For a sequence of inputs (x,y)...(x',y') I want to know the output sequence and am currently using the following code. Any speed up suggestions would be very welcome. A related question is does 'isequal' work faster when comparing rows of matrices than when comparing cells entries (related to another 'checking' code not the code below).

```
function [ T, O ] = mealy( X ,w ,k )
%Given a Mealy machine X, input word w and starting state k, T == 1 means
%this mealy machine does not have sufficient information to give an output
%for input word w. Else T == 0 and O is the output sequence for w. 

L = length(w);
S = zeros(1,L); %state sequence
O = cell(1,L); %letter and output sequence
T = 0;
S(1) = k; %start from state k 

% build output sequence O from input word w
for i = 2:L   
e = w{i-1};
S(i) = X(e(1),e(2),2,S(i-1));
    if S(i) < 0, T = 1; return, end    
t = X(e(1),e(2),1,S(i-1));
    if t < -1.5, T = 1; return, end    
O{i-1} = [e(1),e(2),t];
end

e = w{L};
t = X(e(1),e(2),1,S(L));
if t < -1.5, T = 1;return, end
O{L}= [e(1),e(2),t];
end
```